# Is there any way to download entire collection set stored in Firebase Firestore to the device?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, persistent-storage

I'm using Firebase Cloud Firestore in my iOS app, with persistence enabled option. I want to persist data at the first run of the app and listen to any changes after that.

I only came up with querying every single collection in AppDelegate's `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`:

```
let settings = FirestoreSettings()
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = true

let firestore = Firestore.firestore()
firestore.settings = settings

firestore.collection("1").getDocuments { (snap, error) in
    print("Collection 1 persisted.")
}
firestore.collection("2").getDocuments { (snap, error) in
    print("Collection 2 persisted.")
}
firestore.collection("3").getDocuments { (snap, error) in
    print("Collection 3 persisted.")
}
//....and so on
```

But I don't think this is a good approach. You might have better ideas. Thank you.

Comment: I've found the solution. Do not use Firebase. Go for AWS or implement your own services but do not use Firebase for any `a-bit-complicated` projects of yours. After my last project, I swear that I will never use this useless service ever.

`a-bit-complicated` stands for simply everything! Do you need text-search? Do not use Firebase. Do you need pre-persisting data? Do not use Firebase. Do your users need extra data, addition to email and username, like address etc? Do not use Firebase. Simply, do not use Firebase if you don't want to get a panic attack .